# iphone voice memos 'ping' sound

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm writing a voice recording application, and I'd like to play the ping-ping sound that the voice memos program plays when it finishes recording.  Is there any way to accomplish this programatically?  If not, does anyone know where I can find the sound?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the list of system sound constants?

Comment: sounds promising, but not sure where to find this... is it the same list that includes kSystemSoundID_Vibrate?  It doesn't seem to be included there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a cable to connect your iPhone to your computer, play the ping sound and record it on your computer. I don't know if there are copyright issues with doing this.

One alternative is to use one of the royalty-free sound archives you can find on the web.

If it were me, I'd just recreate the sound with a tone generator and an envelope, and copy and paste it to make it ping twice.

Comment: yeah, i ended up just recording it as you described

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest this:
you must first import the audio framework in your project and add the sound to the bundle

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *sound_string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"/sound.aif"];
NSURL *sound_url= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sound_string];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)sound_url, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundID);
```